# Process.Start crashes without an exception

Tags: c#, linux, mono, process.start

I'm developing a simple compiler, and the final stage after the IL code has been generated is to compile it with the `ilasm` utility, which is where the the crash takes place.

Here is the full code of the method (slightly modified for Stack):

```
public static string ExecuteIL(string filename)
{
  var ilasmp = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
  ilasmp.StartInfo.FileName = "ilasm";
  ilasmp.StartInfo.Arguments = filename;
  //Crash does not happen here:
  ilasmp.Start ();
  ilasmp.WaitForExit ();

  var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/time";
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = "mono " + filename.Replace(".il", ".exe");
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  try{
    //Crash happens HERE, but for some reason the exception does not get thrown
    p.Start ();
  }
  catch{
    throw new Exception ();
  }

  string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  p.WaitForExit ();

  return output;
}
```

Just to make it clear: the crash does not happen when I call `Process.Start` for the first time (`ilasmp.Start ();`), but for some reason this happens later (`p.Start ();`), 
and what's interesting is that an exception does not get thrown.
Or in other words, the code simply crashes.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: @knocte, I think it's one of the latest versions, here is the exact return from `mono --version`: `Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.4 (tarball Fri Jun 10 10:12:47 UTC 2016)`

Comment: what OS? how did you install that version of mono?

Comment: @knocte OS is **fedora**, I installed it using the fedora repositry manager (now dnf), in other words: `dnf install mono`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect errors and output if you're going to set

```
UseShellExecute = true;
```

From Microsoft:

> You must set UseShellExecute to false if you want to set RedirectStandardError to true. Otherwise, reading from the StandardError stream throws an exception.

[UseShellExecute Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RedirectStandardError Property](http://%22https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror(v=vs.110).aspx%22)